# how to read all elements of json array in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have a json file with an array of table names. i want to read, print all those elements one by one and get count of array elements.
How can we achieve this in databricks notebook using scala.

Json file:

```
{
    "application_name": "dca_app",
    "table_list": ["dca_table1", "dca_table2"]
}
```

What i want it:

```
table count = 2 
table1: dca_table1
table2: dca_table2
```

Code:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/mnt/config/sample.json")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
val x = df.select("table_list")
print(x)
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- application_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

dataframe:

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|application_name|          table_list|
+----------------+--------------------+
|         dca_app|[dca_table1, dca_...|
+----------------+--------------------+
```

i tried with code:

```
val tablelist = df.selectExpr("table_list[0]")
tablelist.show()
```

but if i give table_list[i], where i is iterator, code generates error. it expects numeric value here.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want the array values to end up as separate rows or as columns in a single row, so below are both solutions :)

1. Row for each array value:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df.select("application_name", explode("table_list")).show()
```

`explode` does that for arrays, result:

```
+----------------+----------+
|application_name|       col|
+----------------+----------+
|         dca_app|dca_table1|
|         dca_app|dca_table2|
+----------------+----------+
```

2. Column for each value:

```
df.selectExpr(["table_list[%s]" % i for i in range(2)] + ["application_name"]).show()
```

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|table_list[0]|table_list[1]|application_name|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   dca_table1|   dca_table2|         dca_app|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

As you can see you can actually pass a list comprehension into `selectExpr` but it has to be a value defined statically.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.
but I want scala code, what you have suggested works fine with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("/mnt/config/sample.json")
var arrayList = df.select("table_list").toDF.withColumn("table_list",explode($"table_list")).collectAsList.toArray

for (i <- 0 to (arrayList.length)-1)
{
  val filename = arrayList(i).toString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
  println(filename)
}
```